# Using Parameter/Variable in SQL Command text in SSIS where Source is ODBC

Tags: sql, variables, parameters, ssis, odbc

I have an Informix ODBC data source.

I am calling a function to retrieve data from the database.

```
call sp_ccdr('2018-04-23 04:00:00','2018-04-24 03:59:59','0',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'NULL','NULL','f')
```

Now I want to use either a parameter or variable instead of values that I am passing to the function.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks
Abdulquadir

Comment: Yes, generally to do this create a variable for each variable you want, and 1 variable for the command you want. Set the variable that is the command to be  evaluate as expression. Once you have that post some more info if you haven't figured the rest out.

Comment: I am not sure how can I use that variable in SQL command text.

Comment: Set the SQLSourceType to Variable. Then do above.

Comment: @HolmesIV - I have followed the process that you mention but the variables value is not getting evaluated. I am able to evaluate the expression but variable value is not replaced. See my expression: "call sp_ccdr("+"'@[User::startDate]'"+ ","+"'@[User::endDate]'"+",'0', , , , , , , , , , , , 'f')"

Comment: Just to check, you have change the property EvalueAsExpression = TRUE for the variable?

Comment: Yes EvaluateAsExpression is set as True. Can you confirm if the expression created is correct.

Comment: Anyone with any solution?

Comment: I am able to create the variable using expressions editor but how can I use it ODBC source?